# SSRS passing data from master report to subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have a report MRpt which has a subreport SRpt. MRpt has 2 datasets ds1, ds2. SRpt has 1 dataset dsA. All datasets are generated by different stored procedures. I've been trying to pass the data from the master report datasets to the subreport using various suggestions here but it doesn't seem to help so far. Here is a short description of what I try to accomplish.

The MRpt has a tablix that displays some data as below
(For each PartNumber in MRpt, the SRpt will display the history of credit return approval)

```
PartNumber| AskedPrice| AskedQuantity| ApprovedPrice| ApprovedQty
PN_1      |       2.00|            50|          1.50|          50
    InvoiceNumber| InvoicePrice| InvoiceQty| ApprovedPrice| ApproveQty
    240204       |        24.25|         70|          0.50|         50
    220203       |        25.50|       1570|          2.50|       1500

PN_3      |      50.00|            20|         27.50|          20
    InvoiceNumber| InvoicePrice| InvoiceQty| ApprovedPrice| ApproveQty
    240204       |        60.25|        100|         30.50|         70
    220201       |        50.50|       2000|         26.50|       1500
    220109       |        40.50|       1000|         20.50|       1000
```

I need to pass to the SRpt these values from the MRpt datasets: ds1.CustomerID, ds1.StartDate, ds1.EndDate, ds2.PartNumber.

Is it possible? If so, how do I go about to do this? Where should I place the SRpt so it will be shown as above illustration. I'm currently getting error: SubReport could not be shown. If I run the SRpt alone, it displays data correctly.

Please help.

I added some screen shots so you guys can help if I did something wrong.

This is the subreport design view
[image: Subreport design view]

This is the subreport properties from master report
[image: Subreport properties]

This is how I hook up the parameters
[image: Hooking up parameters BillToID]
[image: Part Number]
[image: StartDate and EndDate]
[image: Additional parameter to diplay in subreport]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have properly set up the values you specified as parameters in your subreports then it should be no problem to send them from the master report. There should be a listing of all subreport parameters when you include a subreport and there you would hook up your params.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't figured out where to place the subreport so that it can pick up the proper values passed from master report's datasets. I am thinking it should be somewhere in the tablix of the master report, but I don't where. I added a row in the tablix and put the subreport there, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can add a footer to any group and merge all the cells to create room for the sub report. For example, if you want the sr to render for each line item then place a footer or another row in the detail group and pass the values using Fields!BillToID.Value. If your aim is to have the sub report render after each group the place a footer or another row after the group and use First(Fields!BillToID.Value,'groupName') as you are currently doing. If you want the sub report to run once after the main report then pass the parameters using First(Fields!BillToID.Value,'datasetName')

Comment: I am still not sure what were the issues with my reports, but they're now working.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to submit when hitting the Enter key. Anyway, among other mysterious things that caused the error. I know one of the causes. That was the date I passed from the Header dataset. Although the StartDate and EndDate in the dataset is datetime data type, but I had to do a FormatDateTime with DateFormat.ShortDate before passing the values to the subreport.